# Should I credit the authors for code that is no longer part of the project?

Tags: apache-2.0, github, derivative-works

In one of my projects, I used some code from an Apache version 2 licensed project in the beginning. Now I have completely removed their code and it is no longer part of my project. Do I still have to mention them in my license? Their code is visible only if you go to the older commits of my GitHub repository.

Comment: You might want to check out [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/10141/458).

Answer (score 1):

If their code appears in your repository, it will be helpful to anyone that needs to go through your old commits to have that author information available to them.  However, you could probably get away with just mentioning them on GitHub, rather than mentioning them in your license since they didn't make the final product.

Comment: I think it is then enough, if also the credit is only in the old commits. (Not I was the down.)