Using an oss as a guidebook without license infringement
I know of an open source software (a game engine, server/client/website+database) that does many of the things I need my software to do. I will have to gut and replace certain portions entirely (the combat system) replace the assets (graphics, items, NPCs, dialogue, quests, etc) add entirely new systems (game mechanics/features)
I plan to use the oss as a game plan and code from scratch, leaving our what I don't need and adding things I do need.
How concerned do I need to be, and how much change do I need to consider my software an entirely independent software instead of a derivative work?
Thank you guys for taking the time to answer. I read the Theseus Paradox post, and I see the similarity, however I believe there is room for difference. I'll explain how; I'm asking from the perspective of someone that has never coded anything more complicated than an HTML page, a basic one at that. I do plan a couple years learning a few languages and the basics, however, I imagine it would be a lot easier to design an engine after having seen what one looks like. I'm not so much interested in copying their answers so much as just getting a peek at the test questions as it were.
That being said, how would any programmer ever code anything at all if it is all derivative if they had at any time ever seen the source code of a program which does similar or even the same things? It doesn't seem to me that approach would be efficient, or even viable at all. There has to be some line at which someone has seen other programs and still be able to produce original code. What's a programmer going to do otherwise? Never work on any existing program they didn't code from scratch? That just doesn't even seem like it would work in the real world~
There has to be some line where having seen source code doesn't make any/all code you write in the future derivative. I'm looking for that line.

This question is similar to: Theseus' Paradox applied to code copyright. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I recommend to read MadHatter's answer on this related question: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/can-there-be-a-copyright-on-negative-code - you may not like the answer, but your work will remain a derivative from POV of copyright, unless you write from scratch without using any project as basis. You must not look at an existing solution for reference, but do a clean-room implementation of your idea. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean-room_design Think this way: if it was easy and not copyrightable, why would you need to use it as template?

I would just like to point out as the asker, I realized later that this question is entirely irrelevant to use case. As an open source software I am allowed to both use and modify the software as I please. In the case I just want to use the software to run an MMO, which is what the software does, that is entirely allowed even if I modify the program. It wouldn't be until\unless I wanted to sell the software itself that I might run into problems. This question was a lack of general understanding on my part.

The problem really comes to a head in the last line of your question: you want a bright-line test that enables you to use a copyrighted work (A) in the process of creating a new work (B) while being certain that no infringement has occurred.  But there is no such test.

There has to be some line where having seen source code doesn't make any/all code you write in the future derivative.

There really isn't.  Whether or not the code you write in the future is adjudged to be derivative comes down to how similar it is to the code you've seen, how many different ways there are to write code like that, many other issues that get played out in court all the time after allegations of infringement go to trial.
If you really are simply learning general construction principles from work A before you sit down and write work B de novo, you're probably going to be non-infringing.  If you start with work A and "gut and replace certain portions entirely" in order to make B, you're almost certainly going to be infringing.  But if you want a bright-line test to use in your defence, don't go anywhere near A before you write B.

Thank you very much for your answer. I see how my phrasing could be miconstrued. Perhaps it would be best to just use some other program to learn general language construction. (As a side note, I've seen other comments from you. I appreciate them, thank you for your work on this site.

Thank you for your kind words, and you're very welcome.  I note in passing that if you're happy with an answer to your question, local etiquette is to accept it by clicking on the "tick" outline next to it.  This marks the question as answered to the satisfaction of the questioner, and drives the reputation system for both questioner and answerer.  If not, it's helpful if you can edit the question to clarify what remains, to your mind, unanswered. Please accept my apologies if you already know all this!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
